# How do I add a sidebar to every page except the homepage?

Tags: html, css, ruby, zurb-foundation

I'm planning on using Foundation to make a sidebar that will appear on all pages except the homepage.  I know I have to do an "if" statement in application.html.erb to do that, but I don't know how to name the pages.  This is my vague idea of what I need:

```
if (homepage)
    else 
        <ul class="side-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Using a server side language like PHP/ASP.NET/Ruby or JSP would make this task easy. If you dont, you will need to use a server side include. (SHTML) and your host will need to support it. <!--#include file="sidelist.html" -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Rails you can check the value of `params[:controller]`.
For example:

```
- if params[:controller] == 'main'
  // ....
- else 
  // ...
```

Or, if you are using Sinatra:

```
get('/') do
    title "Home"
    haml :home, format: :html5, locals: { show_sidebar: false }
end
```

and use the `show_sidebar` variable in your view.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can check what page is being rendered using params[:controller] and params[:action]. Probably you should wrap it into some helper like `is_homepage?`. You can also consider using separate layout for home page.

Btw, you can just do

```
unless is_homepage?
  #code
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper called current_page? and put that in your template.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F